# R: Error in dynpred::cindex, Error in if (time[j] > time[i]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the C-statistic of a Cox proportional hazards model, which usually goes pretty smooth with dynpred::cindex. However, now I am running into a bug I never encountered before. Please find below a reproducible example.

## Reproducible example

```
# Produce a random dataset, columns: linear predictor (-1,+1), survival (1-60), vital status (0/1)

TestData <- setnames(as.data.frame(
    cbind(runif(n=20, min=-1, max=1),
    runif(n=20, min=1, max=60),
    round(runif(n=20, min=0, max=1)))),
    c("LP","Overall_survival","Vital_status"))

cindex(Surv(Overall_survival, Vital_status)~LP, data=TestData)
```

In this reproducible I randomly encounter (~50% of the times I run this code) the following error.

## Encountered error dynpred::cindex

```
Error in if (time[j] > time[i]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Although I don't understand why dynpred::cindex shouldn't be able to always calculate a C-statistic with the provided dataset, since these could be realistic data.

Thanks, Steve

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue in my data and found what causes it. The explanation is the following: If in your TestData the highest LP observation has censoring flag 1 in the column Vital_Status you get the error. Or if the TestData the lowest LP observation has censoring flag 0 in column Vital_Status you get the error.

Somehow the package requires that the highest timetoevent value has flag = 0 AND the lowest value to have a flag = 1.

Evert